Issue with uploading shiny app to shinyappio
running into error when trying to upload the app with
rsconnect::deployApp().
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggVennDiagram)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(org.Mm.eg.db)
library(DOSE)
library(rsconnect)

library(BiocManager)
options(repos = BiocManager::repositories())

# library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/phampe/OneDrive - Oregon Health & Science University/Desktop/shiny_app/')
# rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = '~/../Desktop/shiny_app')
# rsconnect::showLogs('~/../Desktop/shiny_app/')


############
lowest_value = 2.225074e-308

# setwd("C:/Users/phampe/OneDrive - Oregon Health & Science University/Desktop/shiny_app/")


testing_file = read.table("liver_regneration_genes_diff_exp_GSEA.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)


file_1 = testing_file[order(testing_file$pvalue, decreasing = FALSE), ]   

file_2 = read.table("both-vs-oct.diffexp.tsv", header = TRUE)

file_3 = read.table("Il6-vs-ctl.diffexp.tsv", header = TRUE)

file_4 = read.table("il6_KO_PDAC-vs-SHAM.qvalue_diffexp.tsv", header = TRUE)
file_4 = file_4[-c(8,9)]

file_5 = read.table("OE_KPC-vs-KPC.qvalue_diffexp.tsv", header = TRUE)
file_5[file_5 == 0] = 2.225074e-308
file_5 = file_5[-c(8,9)]

file_6 = read.table("pdac_adlib-vs-sham_adlib.diffexp_gsea.tsv", header = TRUE)

file_7 = read.table("pdac_fast-vs-sham_fast.diffexp_gsea.tsv", header = TRUE)


Here is my error whenever i run the shiny app in the logs.
Bioconductor version '3.16' is out-of-date; the current release version '3.19'
is available with R version '4.4'; see https://bioconductor.org/install

Error in rsconnect::deployApp("C:/Users/phampe/OneDrive University/Desktop/shiny_app/") : `appDir`, "C:/Users/phampe/OneDrive - University/Desktop/shiny_app/", does not exist.

Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>

Execution halted

Shiny application exiting ...

I've tried hashing out my 'getwd()' and changing my directory

Your app is trying to deploy itself again because you included deployApp() inside the app. Remove that from the app and run it from a separate script instead and all should be well.

setwd() will also cause problems. Anything in the root directory is uploaded during deployment and available to the app. Best to banish that from your workflows in general https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/
